# CHMOD 777 Codeigniter configuration error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am configurating my project on codeigniter and Mamp. When i run it i got CHMOD 7777 error as shown in the image. Does someone know how to make config.php and the other page rewritable.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two method :

**Using your FTP Client**

Click on your files -> Properties -> Permissions : 777.

**Using SSH**

```
chmod 777 /Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/application/main/config/config.php
chmod 777 /Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/started_install.php
```

Comment: i am trying to run it on localhost

Comment: If you are on a MAC, SSH should be okay. Else you can try to directly click on your file -> properties -> permissions.

Comment: i need to run chmod 777 /Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/application/main/config/config.php
chmod 777 /Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/started_install.php on my mac terminal then

Comment: Do you have any error ? Can you tell us the result of the command `ls -lia /Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/application/main/config/config.php` and `ls -lia /Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/started_install.php` ?

Comment: result : IP2Location: Cannot allocate database file at "application/libraries/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-ISP.BIN".

Comment: OKay. This is an other error : there is no file at `/Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/application/libraries/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-ISP.BIN` and it should be one.Have you succeeded to configure your project ?

Comment: yes don't worry i'll mark you as best answer.. can you give me a hint for the second error please

Comment: Already done: there is no file at `/Application/MAMP/httdocs/modena/application/libraries/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-I‌​SP.BIN` and it should be one.